# C++ Qt: Redirect cout from a thread to emit a signal

Tags: multithreading, qt, cout, qthread

In a single thread, I have this beautiful class that redirects all cout output to a QTextEdit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <QScrollBar>

#include "QTextEdit"
#include "QDateTime"

class ThreadLogStream : public std::basic_streambuf<char>, QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ThreadLogStream(std::ostream &stream) : m_stream(stream)
    {
        m_old_buf = stream.rdbuf();
        stream.rdbuf(this);
    }
    ~ThreadLogStream()
    {
        // output anything that is left
        if (!m_string.empty())
        {
            log_window->append(m_string.c_str());
        }

        m_stream.rdbuf(m_old_buf);
    }

protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type v)
    {
        if (v == '\n')
        {
            log_window->append(m_string.c_str());
            m_string.erase(m_string.begin(), m_string.end());
        }
        else
            m_string += v;

        return v;
    }


    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char *p, std::streamsize n)
    {
        m_string.append(p, p + n);

        long pos = 0;
        while (pos != static_cast<long>(std::string::npos))
        {
            pos = m_string.find('\n');
            if (pos != static_cast<long>(std::string::npos))
            {
                std::string tmp(m_string.begin(), m_string.begin() + pos);
                log_window->append(tmp.c_str());
                m_string.erase(m_string.begin(), m_string.begin() + pos + 1);
            }
        }

        return n;
    }

private:
    std::ostream &m_stream;
    std::streambuf *m_old_buf;
    std::string m_string;


    QTextEdit* log_window;
};
```

However, this doesn't work if ANY thread (QThread) is initiated with a cout. This is because all pointers are messed up, and one has to use signals and slots for allowing transfer of data between the sub-thread and the main thread.

I would like to modify this class to emit a signal rather than write to a text file. This requires that this class becomes a Q_OBJECT and be inherited from one. I tried to inherit from `QObject` in addition to `std::basic_streambuf<char>` and added Q_OBJECT macro in the body but it didn't compile.

Could you please help me to achieve this? What should I do to get this class to emit signals that I can connect to and that are thread safe?

Comment: `std::cout` is an object and all threads in a process share that object, so "cout from a thread" doesn't make much sense...

Comment: From someone who would like to use something like this very much: where do you call this class? Can you provide an example of how you use it?

Comment: @GraemeRock Simply in the event loop or the constructor of your thread, call `logStream = new ThreadLogStream(std::cout);`. That will direct everything that goes to `std::cout` to that class. Remember to implement the solution too. This, by itself, doesn't work. It needs `QObject`.

Comment: @the-quantum-physicist I admit, I am getting confused by all the ellipses and renamed variables in the code. Is there a chance the original code with corrections can be posted as an answer?

Comment: @GraemeRock I'm sorry, I can't do that right now. I'm very busy. If you don't get this to working until the weekend, I'll post that code. Deal? Let me know by then.

Comment: @the-quantum-physicist This is unfortunately still not working. I am getting segmentation errors as described below. So I will take you up on your offer.

Comment: @GraemeRock I added it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The `log_window` member variable was removed between the question and the code posted below. How is the signal `sendLogString` connected to the main application ?

Comment: @SAAD You connect it yourself with the `ThreadLogStream` object. Use `QObject::connect(...)` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation needs to happen `QObject`-first:

```
class LogStream : public QObject, std::basic_streambuf<char> {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
};
...
```

If the goal was to minimally modify your code, there's a simpler way. You don't need to inherit `QObject` to emit signals iff you know exactly what slots the signals are going to. All you need to do is to invoke the slot in a thread safe way:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(log_window, "append", Qt::QueuedConnection, 
                          Q_ARG(QString, tmp.c_str()));
```

To speed things up, you can cache the method so that it doesn't have to be looked up every time:

```
class LogStream ... {
  QPointer<QTextEdit> m_logWindow;
  QMetaMethod m_append;

  LogStream::LogStream(...) :
    m_logWindow(...),
    m_append(m_logWindow->metaObject()->method(
             m_logWindow->metaObject()->indexOfSlot("append(QString)") )) {

    ...
  }
};
```

You can then invoke it more efficiently:

```
m_append.invoke(m_logWindow, Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QString, tmp.c_str()));
```

Finally, whenever you're holding pointers to objects whose lifetimes are not under your control, it's helpful to use `QPointer` since it never dangles. A `QPointer` resets itself to 0 when the pointed-to object gets destructed. It will at least prevent you from dereferencing a dangling pointer, since it never dangles.

Comment: I run into segmentation faults on the `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` line at the first call of cout. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: @GraemeRock Please ask a separate question with a complete test case that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For those who need the full "working" answer, here it's. I just copied it because @GraemeRock asked for it.

```
#ifndef ThreadLogStream_H
#define ThreadLogStream_H

#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <QScrollBar>

#include "QTextEdit"
#include "QDateTime"

class ThreadLogStream : public QObject, public std::basic_streambuf<char>
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ThreadLogStream(std::ostream &stream) : m_stream(stream)
    {
        m_old_buf = stream.rdbuf();
        stream.rdbuf(this);
    }
    ~ThreadLogStream()
    {
        // output anything that is left
        if (!m_string.empty())
        {
            emit sendLogString(QString::fromStdString(m_string));
        }

        m_stream.rdbuf(m_old_buf);
    }

protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type v)
    {
        if (v == '\n')
        {
            emit sendLogString(QString::fromStdString(m_string));
            m_string.erase(m_string.begin(), m_string.end());
        }
        else
            m_string += v;

        return v;
    }


    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char *p, std::streamsize n)
    {
        m_string.append(p, p + n);

        long pos = 0;
        while (pos != static_cast<long>(std::string::npos))
        {
            pos = static_cast<long>(m_string.find('\n'));
            if (pos != static_cast<long>(std::string::npos))
            {
                std::string tmp(m_string.begin(), m_string.begin() + pos);
                emit sendLogString(QString::fromStdString(tmp));
                m_string.erase(m_string.begin(), m_string.begin() + pos + 1);
            }
        }

        return n;
    }

private:
    std::ostream &m_stream;
    std::streambuf *m_old_buf;
    std::string m_string;

signals:
    void sendLogString(const QString& str);
};


#endif // ThreadLogStream_H
```

Comment: @GraemeRock How is this class used within the thread ? Can you show the relevant code ?