# Redirecting QThread cout Application Output to QStatusBar? C++

Tags: c++11, cout, stringstream, qthread, qstatusbar

How do I read the `cout` message written in a non-Qt codebase running within a QThread into `QStatusBar`?

**Problems with existing methods:**

- Emitters would not work because the code that is sending cout messages is not based in Qt.
- `QProcess::readAll()` will not work because this is a `QThread`, not a `QProcess`.
- `std::stringstream` seems like it would require `cout` to be replaced (no big deal), but also the string to be read from the same file.
- I cannot get [these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419356/redirect-stdout-stderr-to-a-string) to work due to build errors.
- [Windows solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573724/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-to-some-visible-display-in-a-windows-application) will not work - my OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: I found the answer here, enjoy!: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41047259/5095372

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Qt: Redirect cout from a thread to emit a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317565/c-qt-redirect-cout-from-a-thread-to-emit-a-signal)