# int_type not naming type frustration

Tags: c++, std, typedef, virtual-functions, streambuf

I have a virtual method type `int_type` in [code being adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317565/c-qt-redirect-cout-from-a-thread-to-emit-a-signal#31317565) that is the only case where the code gives the compile error:

```
‘int_type’ does not name a type
 int_type ThreadLogStream::overflow(int_type v)
 ^.
```

**Debugging steps so far**

- If I hover over any other instance of `int_type` in the Qt Creator IDE, it shows `traits_type::int_type std::basic_streambuf::int_type`, implying every other instance of `int_type` should not be causing problems.
- According to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), the int_type does indeed belong to `basic_streambuf`, but calling it `Traits::int_type` did not work.
- I attempted to typedef the problem variable, as demonstrated in the typedefs below, but `char_type` and `traits_type` were not recognized.

threadlogstream.cpp

```
...
int_type ThreadLogStream::overflow(int_type a)
{
    int_type b = a; //This gives no errors

    return b;
}
...
```

threadlogstream.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>

//typedef std::basic_streambuf< char_type, traits_type> base_class;
//typedef typename base_class::int_type int_type;

class ThreadLogStream :  public QObject, std::basic_streambuf<char> {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ThreadLogStream(std::ostream &stream);
    ~ThreadLogStream();

protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type v); // This gives no errors
    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char *p, std::streamsize n);
}
```

Please help - I am losing hair over this.

Comment: This is not supposed to compile if `int_type` is not seen in global namespace. You are supposed to use qualified name for return type when a function is declared outside of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your `int_type` is supposed to stand for `std::basic_streambuf<>::int_type`. In that case in an *out-of-class* member definition you are supposed to write

```
ThreadLogStream::int_type ThreadLogStream::overflow(int_type a)
{
  ...
```

i.e. use a *qualified* name for the function return type. Parameter names are looked up in class scope (which is why a mere `int_type` compiles fine in the parameter list). But return types are looked up in the enclosing scope, which is why you have to quality it explicitly.

That is how it has always been in C++.

However, the return type in trailing return type syntax (available since since C++11) is also looked up in class scope, which means that you can alternatively do this

```
auto ThreadLogStream::overflow(int_type a) -> int_type
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to make it a trailing return type, like so:

```
auto ThreadLogStream::overflow(int_type v) -> int_type {
    // ...
}
```

Explanation: `int_type` needs to be looked up in the scope of `ThreadLogStream`, but if you have a leading return type, it will be looked up in namespace scope since it comes *before* you mention the name `ThreadLogStream::overflow`, which triggers lookup in the scope of `ThreadLogStream`. By placing the return type *after* the *qualified-id*, this problem is avoided.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `auto` in front?

Comment: @Pixelchemist yes, sorry, I fixed it